# mklink - why can't I use . as the destination path?

Tags: cmd

```
# current folder is C:\Users\me\abc 
mklink /d C:\tmp\def .                # C:\tmp\def points to C:\tmp
mklink /d C:\tmp\def C:\Users\me\abc  # C:\tmp\def points to C:\Users\me\abc
```

So I just cannot use single dot to represent the current folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want

```
mklink /d C:\tmp\def %CD%
```

Using "." will just create the link to point to the directory the link resides in, because it's resolved when it's accessed, not at the time you're creating it.